# Three.js reuse geometry for faceColors and vertexColors

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I want the same object to be rendered twice, once on-screen and once off-screen. The on-screen mesh has a geometry and a MeshLambertMaterial. This material has `vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors`. The off-screen mesh has the same geometry and a MeshBasicMeterial with `vertexColors: THREE.FaceColors`. During initial setup each faceColor is set to a unique color. Each vertexColor is set to a single color (Later these vertexcolors can change by "painting" on the object).

Then I want to render both object. In **[this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E3F4f/2/)** you see how that looks with two scenes rendered side by side. The object with the MeshLambertMeterial is now half red to make things clearer. As you can see, both scenes seem to use the same material. Also, when I switch the order I get the following error:

> [.WebGLRenderingContext]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glDrawElements: attempt to access out of range vertices in attribute 1.

To make things even weirder, when run the fiddle I see the object rendered with the MeshBasicMaterial twice. However, when I run the **exact** same code locally, I see the object rendered with the MeshLambertMaterial twice.

Eventually I want the object with the MeshBasicMeterial to render to a rendertarget, but with that I run into the same problems. I want to be able to show the object with the LambertMetarial on screen and when I hover over the object with the mouse, to get the color in that position in the renderTarget, where the BasicMaterial is rendered to.

I hope it is clear what the problem is, if not, please let me know.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E3F4f/2/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EDIT: Issue resolved.

When using `WebGLRenderer`, two meshes having different materials can now share a geometry.

three.js r.88

Comment: Yes, that does work, but it is not the most efficient way. Especially when you have large geometries you can notice a performance drop. Thanks anyway, also about the comment on refactoring in the fiddle.

Comment: Do not share geometries with meshes having different materials.

Comment: I believe [that requirement is gone in recent versions of three.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/12718#issuecomment-351333955), and geometries can now be shared with meshes having different materials.

Comment: @DonMcCurdy Updated post. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, they are not gone.. at least in my app

Answer (score 0):

First of all, always make sure you try the latest three.js everywhere. especially, do not use the jsfiddle's r54 but instead use an up-to-date external resource like http://threejs.org/build/three.min.js - this solves one of your problems.

The main thing is that you need to update the vertex colors between the render calls (and if they are changed, you have to do that anyway). Here's what does the trick:

```
function render () {
    var SCREEN_WIDTH = WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT = HEIGHT;
    camera.aspect = 0.5 * SCREEN_WIDTH / SCREEN_HEIGHT;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

    renderer.clear();

    geometry.colorsNeedUpdate = true;

    // left side
    renderer.setViewport( 0, 0,  0.5 * SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT );
    renderer.render( scene, camera );

    geometry.colorsNeedUpdate = true;    

    // right side
    renderer.setViewport( 0.5 * SCREEN_WIDTH, 0, 0.5 * SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT );
    renderer.render( pickRenderScene, camera );
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/E3F4f/4/

Comment: The core problem is the sharing of geometries in this case, but in some cases it is possible -- you just need to really understand what is going on in the inner-workings of the library.

Comment: @WestLangley: true, nowing what goes on in the library is very important. However the documentation of three.js falls short in many cases. I really hope that some time will be put into explaining the inner-workings a bit more.

Comment: @morris4: this works great, without cloning the geometry. I will test this solution more thoroughly tomorrow with a renderTarget. I thought I tried this before, but maybe in the other order. Any idea why the error comes up when the order is changed?

Comment: I couldn't wait, so I did a quick test. For some reason this solution makes the framerate drop from ~60 to ~20. Can that have to with the colorsupdate? When cloning the geometry like @WestLangley suggested, the framerate drops only to ~50. But this is less memory efficient right?

Comment: I was trying to answer the question under the given constraints - but yes, updating a large geometry buffern (twice) every frame is costly and a bad idea. So +1 for WestLangley :) anyway, to find your bottleneck, we'd have to know what exactly you're trying to do

Comment: I want to do picking to find out the face visible onder the cursor, that's basically it. I could do raypicking, but this is slow for large meshes. I have implemented an octree, but then I run into memory problems for large meshes. Someone suggested off-screen rendering as being the holy grail. When I render the same mesh off-screen with each face having a distinct color, then I could simply check for the color at the position of the mouse in the off-screen render to find the face directly. To be complete, there's always just one object in the scene (besides lights, camera etc.)

Comment: how many faces does your geometry have, roughly? does the geometry ever change? is the complete object on the screen all the time? maybe you can get away with some level of detail techniques.