# Three.js: WebGL (error) drawing texture on a plane

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

The problem:

> Ok i'm trying draw a few planes with three.js and one of these have a texture but is not drawed when i use WebGLRenderer(), if i change the renderer by CanvasRenderer(), draw the texture, the problem is with WebGL/Three.js.

The error:

> Firefox console error: "WebGL: drawElements: bound vertex attribute buffers do not have sufficient size for given indices from the bound element array"

**UPDATE**

> Google chrome error: "[.WebGLRenderingContext]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glDrawElements: attempt to access out of range vertices in attribute 1"

The Code:

```
    //scene-camera
    var scene = new THREE.Scene ();
    var camera =  new THREE.PerspectiveCamera (90, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
    camera.position.z = 600;
    camera.updateMatrixWorld (true);
    scene.add (camera);

    //renderer
    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer ();
    renderer.setSize (window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    document.body.appendChild (renderer.domElement);

    //geometry  
    var geometryPlane = new THREE.PlaneGeometry (600, 400);

    //textures
    var textureWall1 = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture ('textures/wall1.jpg');
    textureWall1.anisotropy = renderer.getMaxAnisotropy();

    //materials 
    var materialWall1 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial ({map: textureWall1});

    //objets-plane      
    var plane = new THREE.Mesh (geometryPlane, materialWall1);

    //vectors 
    var vecX = new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 0);
    var vecY = new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0);
    var vecZ = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1);
    var vec0 = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0);

    //add scene-camera position of the objects 
    scene.add (plane);

    var render = function (){
        //translate 
        plane.translateOnAxis (vecZ, 300);

        renderer.render (scene, camera);
    }
    render ();
```

I think is a problem with de resolutions of the picture and the plane... but i already have try change it, but it still with the same result, if you need, the resolutions are:

Wall1.jpg (598, 398)px...

Thanks for any help!

PD: this isn't all code, the rest is others planes and materials (colors)

Comment: Did you try re-sizing your texture to 512x512px?

Comment: If you take out the anisotropy and you still have the error you would need to create a fiddle to look at some more code.

Comment: On google chrome console, drop this error: "GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glDrawElements: attempt to access out of range vertices in attribute 1"... if is an error of buffer uvs or vertices... how i can setting this attributes?

Comment: See if this solves your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20550021/three-js-reuse-geometry-for-facecolors-and-vertexcolors/20551325#20551325

Comment: The error is out but dont draw the wall with the texture...

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14959276/load-image-to-a-cube-three-js/14964016#14964016

Comment: Calling by console is the same, but the good new is :D, calling requestAnimationFrame(render) works, i added this call "var animation = function () { renderer.render (scene, camera); } and add to render for later move the planes without repetition of the animation.
Gracias... estoy muy feliz :)